How should I glue back plastic parts of my Laptop corner? How to make the corner and scratches on the back visually good again?
my laptop fell a while ago and the corner broke (plastic parts) I have the broken parts and want to make it look good again. Which glues and/or paints should i get to repair it and also fill the cracks?
It also has some scratches on its back(second image), is it possible to fix them too?


Not sure if this is on topic here, but generally speaking, two-part epoxy cements are strong and adhere well to some plastics and most metals. You might also look for a replacement case, either new, or from a "dead" machine.

Very carefully, but there's not really a "right" way, per se. Just do it carefully. Making it look good is entirely up to your skill or care or patience in doing the work.
